# How to get the media title and url to the media entity

Tags: 8, theming

I have a media file field `field_file` where the data is saved like:

```
title: Media Entity 01
file: media_entity_01.pdf
```

Using twig, is it possible to output the title of the file and the path?

When rendering the full entity using the 'Render Entity' display mode, I can only get the display to output something like this:

```
<a href="/media_entity_01.pdf">media_entity_01.pdf</a>
using twig like this:
{{ content.field_file }}
```

when i want it to output like this:

```
<a href="/media_entity_01.pdf">Media Entity 01</a>
using something like this:
<a href="{{content.field_file.entity.uri.value}}">{{content.field_file.GET_THE_TITLE}}</a>
```

Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Got it figured out. Steps:

In `Structure > Media Types > File > Manage Display`, set the format as `Generic File`, click the gear icon, and turn on `Use description as link text`.

Next, inside of `Structure > Media Types > File > Manage Fields`, edit the `field_media_file` field and **make sure the checkbox for** `Enable description field` **is checked**. Now, when creating a media file entity, there is a description field that can be filled and will display as the link text.

Comment: As usual... this is buried in the CMS... albeit, in a logical location...